# Get position of an attached object

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm attaching a box to an editable poly.

```
endBox = (Box length:0 width:0 pos:loc)
anchorBox.attach(endBox) anchorBox
```

I'm trying to, now that it's attached to anchorBox, get the location of endBox. Is this possible? I tried `anchorBox.endBox.pos` but that doesn't work. Doesn't seem to be an answer to this question anywhere.

Thanks!

Edit: I just discovered that attaching deletes the object endBox. Is there a way to do this so I can attach it but still preserve the object so I can keep track of the coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's better to parent the endbox? So you'll have an hierarchy and endbox will follow anchorbox?

```
Endbox.parent = anchorbox
```

No you can just query the endbox for it's position or transform.

```
endbox.position
in coordsys world endbox.position
in coordsys parent endbox.position
```

etc